# Adding a row above header columns in python pandas dataframe, without any file read/write

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I need to add a row above the header columns in a dataframe, which will be converted to an excel file, with the limitation that there cannot be any reading / writing of files locally. Because of this, I am unable to use `open('filename.xls', 'w') as f:`

This is because the script is to be run in a place where files cannot be read/written locally.

So for example, I want something like this

```
text here
*animal* *no_of_legs* *name*
cat       4            meow
bird      2            chirp
rabbit    2            bun
```

I have an array allAnimals consisting of all the animals data.
I tried `allAnimals.insert(0,['text here])` then `df = pd.DataFrame(allAnimals, columns=['animals', 'no_of_legs', 'name'])` to convert as a dataframe. I then use `df.to_excel(xxx, index=False)` but I get something like this instead:

```
*animal* *no_of_legs* *name*
text here
cat       4            meow
bird      2            chirp
rabbit    2            bun
```

Alternatively, another method I tried involved creating a new dataframe storing only 'text here', and then tried to use concat but it doesn't add the data horizontally. It adds a new column instead. The same goes for append. So this would be what I get:

```
            *animal* *no_of_legs* *name*
text here
             cat       4            meow
             bird      2            chirp
             rabbit    2            bun
```

I have read some other questions similar to this but they are not very applicable to my case, as such, I am unable to solve this. Any tips would be appreciated!

[Is it possible to add a row above the headers in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65038543/is-it-possible-to-add-a-row-above-the-headers-in-pandas)

[Add rows *on top of* column names Pandas Dataframe as header info?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50512866/add-rows-on-top-of-column-names-pandas-dataframe-as-header-info)

[How to add an empty row on top of the header row in a dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63931457/how-to-add-an-empty-row-on-top-of-the-header-row-in-a-dataframe)

[Add rows back to the top of a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73175476/add-rows-back-to-the-top-of-a-dataframe)

Comment: ok, i am trying it out. if it doesn't work, i shall ask for my question to be reopened.

Comment: The question did mention that there cannot be any reading / writing of files locally, so the proposed solution of writing pandas dataframe to excel seems to be rather inapplicable.
This question seems to be completely different in that it is trying to ask for solutions on working with DataFrames on pandas, rather than writing pandas dataframe to excel.

Comment: @jezrael im sorry, but i tried the method in the proposed solution, it was not helpful because for the portion of "pd.ExcelWriter(file-name, engine="xlsxwriter")", i am unable to read the file-name. I tried replacing it with my version and I faced an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can edit your dataframe's column with an additional column index level by making it a MultiIndex. Assign df.columns to be pd.MultiIndex:

Attempting to reproduce the example:

```
import pandas as pd


allAnimals = [['cat', 4, 'meow'], ['bird', '2', 'chirp'], ['rabbit', 2 ,'bun']]


df = pd.DataFrame(allAnimals, columns= ['animals', 'no_of_legs', 'name'])

df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
    zip(['text here', '', ''], 
        df.columns))
df
```

Output:

[image: output]

Remove the index column accordingly if needed.

This may be of help to you: [working with pandas additional column index](https://www.delftstack.com/howto/python-pandas/how-to-add-header-row-to-a-pandas-dataframe/)

Comment: what is the df.columns line supposed to do? Could you include some explanation please, instead of just supplying the code?

Comment: alright ill edit my post accordingly :)

Answer (score 1):

The above answer was a big step forward in answering the question, however, it involved multi-index which then disallowed me from using index=False in `df.to_excel(xxx, index=False)`. This led to the excel file being off-format, since it is now index=True.

This means I got an excel file like this:
[image: excel file with formatting issues]

Honestly, the only complication here is the limitation of not being able to read/write locally.

I went on to research on how to fix this, and came across some articles:

[How to hide the rows index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57961010/how-to-hide-the-rows-index/57961084#57961084)

[Get rid of index while outputting multi header pandas dataframe to excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54987313/get-rid-of-index-while-outputting-multi-header-pandas-dataframe-to-excel)

I couldn't implement the first website's answer because I couldn't supply a local path. I decided to use the second website's first workaround, which involved using openpyxl and using bytesIO.

In case anyone needs this in the future, here's the implementation:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook, Workbook

in_memory_fp = io.BytesIO()
df.to_excel(in_memory_fp)
in_memory_fp.seek(0,0)

workbook = load_workbook(in_memory_fp)
worksheet = workbook['Sheet1']

worksheet.delete_cols(1)
worksheet.delete_rows(3)

for i in worksheet.values:
    print(i)

workbook.save(in_memory_fp)
```

and then now, the excel will be nicely formatted like this:[image: excel file with nicer format]